# How to convert NULLs in a Dataframe String column to a default value using WHEN condition in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a pyspark dataframe obtained from reading a table as below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = spark.sql("select employe_header, employee_number from DB.TABLE where substring(SOME_DATECOLUMN, 1, 4) in ('2021') and employee_number is null;")
```

My criteria is to check if the employee_number is empty or NULL or zeroes and update it to `NA` if any of the conditions are satisfied.
I wrote the code like below.

```
data = data.withColumn("employee_number", F.when((col("employee_number") == "") | (col("employee_number").isNull()) | (col("employee_number") == "0"), "NA"))
data.printSchema()
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- employe_header: string (nullable = true)
 |-- employee_number: string (nullable = true)
```

But when I check the data inside dataframe, it still contains NULLs in the column: employee_number which can be seen below.
`data.select('employee_number').display()`
[image]

Could anyone let me know what is the mistake I am doing here and how can I correct it ?

Comment: Agreed with @anky. You might wanna assign it to a different dataframe name. DataFrames are immutable structure, they cannot be overwritten

Comment: Its python, although you are right - dataframe are immutables - he can override the data variable. and its exactly what he does.

Try to wrap with brackets (, ) the logical operators within the when.
Another thing is that maybe the strings are not equal to "" but are nulls.
so isNotNull() check within the when can solve the issue

Comment: @BennyElgazar the question was edited after the comments. Initially OP didnot show us overriding of the `data` variable and hence the comment :) Anyways, its tough to guess without seeing the distinct values of this column but I am assuming OP  should also check for `'null'` as a string in the when condition.

Comment: @anky I assigned the Dataframe to a different variable and it started showing the results I was expecting.